# telegraf.js ошибка при запуске бота

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

```
Failed to process updates. { Error: 401: Unauthorized
    at buildConfig.then.then.then.then (/home/allax/node_modules/telegraf/core/network/client.js:262:17)
    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)
  code: 401,
  response: { ok: false, error_code: 401, description: 'Unauthorized' },
  description: 'Unauthorized',
  parameters: {},
  on:
   { method: 'getUpdates?offset=0&limit=100&timeout=30',
     payload: {} } }
```

При запуске самого обычного бота из туториалов

Comment: *Unauthorized?*

Comment: Покажите Ваш код пожалуйста.
Не совсем понятно... Ругается на отсутствие токена для авторизации

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: 401: Unauthorized
```

Это значит, что вы указали некорректный токен бота. Получить его можно в @BotFather